# how an array index could be a file path

Tags: plugins

In the function below at the end the variable $plugin_path is used as an index of an array.

How could it be possible since some lines above we have the call to a function which returns a string (see the code line $plugin_path = wp_normalize_path( dirname( $file ) ).

Is it normal or is it a PHP trick?

Could somebody helps me to clear out this issue?

Many thanks

```
function wp_register_plugin_realpath( $file ) {
    global $wp_plugin_paths;

    // Normalize, but store as static to avoid recalculation of a constant   value
    static $wp_plugin_path = null, $wpmu_plugin_path = null;
    if ( ! isset( $wp_plugin_path ) ) {
        $wp_plugin_path   = wp_normalize_path( WP_PLUGIN_DIR   );
        $wpmu_plugin_path = wp_normalize_path( WPMU_PLUGIN_DIR );
    }

    $plugin_path = wp_normalize_path( dirname( $file ) );
    $plugin_realpath = wp_normalize_path( dirname( realpath( $file ) ) );

    if ( $plugin_path === $wp_plugin_path || $plugin_path === $wpmu_plugin_path ) {
        return false;
    }

    if ( $plugin_path !== $plugin_realpath ) {
        $wp_plugin_paths[ $plugin_path ] = $plugin_realpath;
    }

    return true;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

The string given by `$plugin_path` is used as an array key for `$wp-plugin_paths`, this is pretty standard behaviour in setting an array so it can be accessed later, to retrieve `$plugin_realpath` via `$wp_plugin_paths[$plugin_path]`.

If you want to see how it all comes out you can do:

```
add_action('init','print_plugin_paths');
function print_plugin_paths() {
    global $wp_plugin_paths;
    foreach ($wp_plugin_paths as $key => $value) {
        echo "Plugin Path: ".$key." - ";
        echo "Real Path: ".$value."<br>";
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm a newbie in wordpress. To test your function I must create a must used plugin in mu_plugin directory and execute wordpress, is it?

Comment: yes that is a good way to test it, any PHP file in the `/wp-content/mu-plugins/` (note the `-` not `_`) itself - not in a subdirectory of it - will automatically execute and just remove it when you're done.